# Is there something like OLE available in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, ole, rcp

We have three Eclipse RCP applications running in parallel. Now I need to implement another RCP that displays/operates part of the running applications. In Windows the solution would be to provide the functionality as OLE-Control.

How can I achieve the same thing in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

There is some limited OLE interation (OLE Documents and ActiveX controls) in the OLE SWT package available in the win32 version of SWT.  You would need to make sure that you ran different versions of this RCP app on win32 vs another platform or you encapsulated any per-platform code in a fragment.

See http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-ActivexSupportInSwt/index.html for an introduction to SWT OLE integration.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an OLE/inter process communication within Eclipse. You can stick to plain Java way of doing things (such as a TCP-IP connection between processes)